# Replacing Cell Value with String

Tags: excel

I have this Excel file where i have a list of items on the left and a list of who drops that item on the right (gaming wise)

[image: http://i.imgur.com/oWSYl6G.png]

On the right side, is there a way for me to automatically (i mean, not 1 by 1) put in the column to the right of (for example) "300", the name "Lette Pants"?

Of course, this should happen to all items, not just "300", by making a search on the left side searching for the name corresponding to the number and replacing the white cell with it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a vlookup for this.

In cell L154, you can put:

```
=VLOOKUP(K154, A:B, 2, 0)
```

I'm not too familiar with tables in excel, but I think putting this formula there will also fill in the other cells automatically (in that column). Otherwise, just drag the formula (or copy/paste) it down.

`K154` is what's the formula looking for (here, it's the 'id' 300)

`A:B` is the table the formula looks in, which is in columns A (where the 'id' is) and the result you want in column B.

`2` means the second column in table `A:B`. If you wanted to get the stuff from column D, you would use `=VLOOKUP(K154, A:D, 4, 0)` instead (D is the 4th column, counting A as 1).

Finally, the `0` is for exact match. Setting it to true would make the formula return the corresponding value immediately lower than the value you're looking for if that value is not found. (e.g. you could say that if there is no 300, it will look for 299, then 298, etc until it finds one)

Comment: Thx! Worked Perfectly. I was having some problems but then i realised my Office is in Portuguese -_-

Comment: @FabioAbreu Oh... oops! ^^; I think you use semicolons instead of commas?

Comment: just that and that its not Vlookup but Procv. Thx a lot for the help. i really love this community. i post a question and 5minutes later is answered *.*

Comment: @FabioAbreu Oh wow, okay, I have never head of Procv xD. But yea, it often depends on the question, how it is asked and whether it's clear or not. The picture definitely helps assessing the problem (if any)!